# When does it become impossible to lose a game of FreeCell?

Tags: reference-request, card-games

After spending more time than I should playing FreeCell, I've been wondering about the following:

> At what point in the game does it become impossible for someone to lose?

"losing" probably isn't very well defined, so I'll give some idea of what I'm looking for:

- When no further moves are possible (this is something the computer program seems to easily figure out for me)
- When winning is impossible (e.g. the player is stuck with moving a single card between stacks A and B; the beginning of unwinnable FreeCell games), although technically moves are still possible

I suppose for the purposes of this question, I'll restrict my attention to the set-up of the game used on Windows.

Are there any well-defined scenarios that answer my question, and what might I want to read to get some better understanding of this problem (or related ones)?

Comment: My guess is that you're looking for Game Trees.